# What exactly is the difference between Android View Model and a Singleton class

Tags: android

What exactly is the difference between Android View Model and a Singleton class if we are not using LiveData. Because a singleton class would also exist across activity orientation changes. Please let me know on this. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Sagar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A singleton is unique for your entire process. A `ViewModel` instance is unique for a single `Activity` class (and, if you start multiple activities of that class, it is unique for each started activity).

Comment: thank you for the reply. Can we also use the same ViewModel across activity A and activity B ?

Comment: @SagarEkbote: No, sorry.

Comment: @SagarEkbote I think you are referring to the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55307761/create-viewmodel-with-application   
 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329800/update-viewmodel-from-a-different-class/55329832?noredirect=1#55329832

Comment: You can access the same view model across activities. See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: @Phiil: The section that you linked to is about sharing viewmodel instances between fragments, not activities.

Comment: Technically we can share the same viewModel across activities if we share the same viewModelStore between those activities, but we will be responsible for for handling that viewModelStore and make it survive the configuration change..but that would be non sensical because then we are essentially solving the same thing what viewModel is designed to solve for free...

Comment: (Singleton)Application Scoped Object and (ViewModel)Activity Scoped Object