# Cannot create an instance of class | ViewModel with (application: Application) argument

Tags: java, android, kotlin, viewmodel

I've tried to pass the arguments from DetailUserViewModel and ended up getting an error "Cannot create an instance of class", if I remove the arguments (application: Application), the app is working.

Any answer is appreciated because it helped me with the final test.
Thank you so much.

Here is my codeblock:

**DetailUserViewModel**

```
class DetailUserViewModel(application: Application): ViewModel() {

    private val userRepository: UserRepository = UserRepository(application)

    private val _userDetail = MutableLiveData<DetailUserResponse>()
    val userDetail: LiveData<DetailUserResponse> = _userDetail

    private val _listFollows = MutableLiveData<List<Item>>()
    val listFollows: LiveData<List<Item>> = _listFollows

    private val _isLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isLoading: LiveData<Boolean> = _isLoading

    fun insert(user: User){
        userRepository.insertUser(user)
    }

    fun delete (user: User){
        userRepository.delete(user)
    }

    fun getUserFavoritesById(id: Int): LiveData<List<User>>{
        return userRepository.getUserFavoritesById(id)
    }



    fun setUserDetail(username: String) {
        showLoading(true)
        val client = ApiConfig.getApiService().getDetailUser(username)
        client.enqueue(object : Callback<DetailUserResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<DetailUserResponse>,
                response: Response<DetailUserResponse>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    showLoading(false)
                    val responseBody = response.body()
                    if (responseBody != null) {
                        _userDetail.value = responseBody
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DetailUserResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("Failure", "${t.message}")
            }
        })
    }

    fun getFollowers(username: String) {
        showLoading(true)
        val client = ApiConfig.getApiService().getFollowers(username)
        client.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Item>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Item>>, response: Response<List<Item>>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    showLoading(false)
                    val responseBody = response.body()
                    if (responseBody != null) {
                        _listFollows.value = responseBody
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Item>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("Failure", "${t.message}")
            }

        })
    }

    fun getFollowing(username: String) {
        showLoading(true)
        val client = ApiConfig.getApiService().getFollowing(username)
        client.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Item>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Item>>, response: Response<List<Item>>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    showLoading(false)
                    val responseBody = response.body()
                    if (responseBody != null) {
                        _listFollows.value = responseBody
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Item>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("Failure", "${t.message}")
            }

        })
    }

    private fun showLoading(b: Boolean) {
        if (b) {
            _isLoading.value = true
        } else {
            _isLoading.value = false
        }
    }

}
```

**DetailUserViewModelFactory**

```
class DetailUserViewModelFactory(private val application: Application): ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(DetailUserViewModel::class.java)) {
            return DetailUserViewModel(application) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class: ${modelClass.name}")
    }
}
```

**DetailUserActivity**

```
class DetailUserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailUserBinding

    private val viewModel by viewModels<DetailUserViewModel> {
        DetailUserViewModelFactory(application)
    }

    companion object {
        var EXTRA_DATA = "extra_data"

        @StringRes
        private val TAB_TITLES = intArrayOf(
            R.string.tab_text_1,
            R.string.tab_text_2
        )
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDetailUserBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        supportActionBar?.elevation = 0f

        val username = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DATA).toString()

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.setUserDetail(username.toString())
            viewModel.userDetail.observe(this@DetailUserActivity) { userDetail ->
                dataList(userDetail)
            }
            viewModel.isLoading.observe(this@DetailUserActivity) { isLoading ->
                if (isLoading) {
                    binding.profileDetail.progressBarDetail.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    binding.profileDetail.progressBarDetail.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }

        val viewPager: ViewPager2 = binding.viewPager
        val tabs: TabLayout = binding.tabs

        val adapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this)
        adapter.username = username

        viewPager.adapter = adapter

        TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewPager) { tabs, position ->
            tabs.text = resources.getString(TAB_TITLES[position])
        }.attach()

        binding.btnFavorite.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@DetailUserActivity,
                "Ditambahkan ke favorit!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            binding.btnFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_clicked)
        }
    }


    private fun dataList(userDetail: DetailUserResponse) {
        binding.apply {
            val tvName = binding.profileDetail.profileName
            if (userDetail.name == null) {
                tvName.text = userDetail.login
            } else {
                tvName.text = userDetail.name
            }
            profileDetail.tvProfileUsername.text = "@${userDetail.login}"
            profileDetail.tvProfileFollower.text = "${userDetail.followers} Followers"
            profileDetail.tvProfileFollowing.text = "${userDetail.following} Following"
            Glide.with(this@DetailUserActivity)
                .load(userDetail.avatarUrl)
                .into(binding.profileDetail.ivProfileDetail)
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Console**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.uberalles.githubuser, PID: 31216
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.uberalles.githubuser.activity.DetailUserViewModel
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:204)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:83)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
    at com.uberalles.githubuser.activity.FollowFragment$viewModel$2.invoke(FollowFragment.kt:24)
    at com.uberalles.githubuser.activity.FollowFragment$viewModel$2.invoke(FollowFragment.kt:20)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at com.uberalles.githubuser.activity.FollowFragment.getViewModel(FollowFragment.kt:20)
    at com.uberalles.githubuser.activity.FollowFragment.onViewCreated(FollowFragment.kt:52)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3128)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1817)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1729)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:317)
    at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.placeFragmentInViewHolder(FragmentStateAdapter.java:341)
    at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:276)
    at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:67)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchChildAttached(RecyclerView.java:8291)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:924)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:9344)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:9302)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:9289)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1676)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1622)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:687)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4604)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3981)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26357)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChild(ViewGroup.java:6952)
    at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onMeasure(ViewPager2.java:498)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26357)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:632)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:733)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem(BasicMeasure.java:160)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:291)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1594)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1708)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26357)
```

Fix the error of Cannot create an instance of class and make it to DetailActivity

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55307761/create-viewmodel-with-application but TBH i don´t understand why the repository needs the Application... maybe you need to access to sharepreferences or database? in this case pass by constructor the instance that you need, not the application.  And you can use another approach, for example, a dependency injector as Hilt because "it is easier than Dagger"

Comment: @ManuelMato
Yes, I need to access sharedpreferences and database soon, I still dont know the answer

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an `Application` parameter passed into your VM's constructor, you need to subclass `AndroidViewModel` instead.

```
class DetailUserViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application)
```

There are a few other default parameters you can include (`SavedStateHandle` and a `CoroutineScope`), for anything else you need to [create a factory for your `ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories), either by hand or using a *dependency injection* library like *Hilt* (which can create the factory for you)

Comment: I still got an error after I changed to AndroidViewModel

java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.uberalles.githubuser.activity.DetailUserViewModel

Comment: @arizonapradana the stacktrace (the full error message with all the lines explaining what's happened) will tell you the problem - edit your question and add it in a code block if you need some help interpreting it

Comment: thank you for reminding me, now updated with the stacktrace

Comment: @arizonapradana is that all there is? There aren't any `"Caused by...` sections following it? There isn't any more to it than just subclassing `AndroidViewModel` and making sure you have a constructor that takes a single `Application` parameter. I made a mistake in the answer though, I forgot you need to pass that `Application` to the superclass constructor too, so make sure you're calling `AndroidViewModel(application)` - the IDE should warn you if you haven't

Comment: I can't believe I fixed it, the error was on the FollowFragment which was using "viewModels by lazy" instead of "viewModels by viewModels<DetailUserViewModel>.
Now the application is working fine when I clicked the detail user.

Comment: @arizonapradana all right cool, glad you fixed it!