# Update viewmodel from a different class

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am trying to understand ViewModel and LiveData.

In MainActivity, I am observing LiveData
In MyTask, I am setting data on the LiveData, that should be displayed in the activity.

Problem is data set in MyTask is not getting updated on the UI.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyViewModel viewModel;
    private TextView tv2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewModel.setNameData("Button clicked");
                new MyTask(getApplication()).execute();
            }
        });

        viewModel.getNameData().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                tv2.setText(s);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**ViewModel class**

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> nameData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MutableLiveData<String> getNameData() {
        return nameData;
    }

    public void setNameData(String name) {
        nameData.postValue(name);
    }


    public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }
}
```

**MyTask class**

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private MyViewModel viewModel;

    public MyTask(Application application){
        viewModel = new MyViewModel(application);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        viewModel.setNameData("Done task");

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't create a new instance of `MyViewModel` in your task, pass in the one you obtained in your Activity

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Is there a way I can create an instance in task without passing? I know it's not a good idea to have singleton ViewModel class

Comment: Just do `new MyTask(viewModel)`

Comment: Yes, I am trying to explore other ways, in which I do not want to pass any activity reference.

Comment: You're not passing the Activity reference, you're passing the ViewModel reference. 

Comment: Although to be honest, it would make more sense to just create the AsyncTask inside the ViewModel, instead of here in the Activity's button's onClick listener.

Comment: Yes, ViewModel is created in the activity, and if we pass viewmodel reference to another class, activity is still tied up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54

> "Instead of trying to solve this with libraries or extensions to the
>   Architecture Components, it should be faced as a design problem. We
>   recommend you treat your events as part of your state."

We should not share the livedata or viewmodel instance.

```
Activity -> Viewmodel -> Repository
```

Activity should contain instance of a viewModel. If the button is clicked, it should be notified to the viewModel which shall start the task. After getting response in viewmodel, update the livedata. It will automatically get notified in the Activity.

Comment: What if we want to pass the ViewModel to another class and call the update and insert functions on the ViewModel from that class instead of the one in which it was initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new instance just pass the created instance of viewmodel

```
public MyTask(MyViewModel myViewModel)  { 
   viewmodel = myViewModel;
}
```

And then try to update the Ui

> To update the observer the viewmodel needs the activity context ..inside which the livedata is observed.. you are creating a separate instance of the viewmodel inside the AsyncTask..

Comment: It's already there in the MainActivity. I am creating using         viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

In MyTask, I am using new keyword.

Comment: You are using application context ...that's not the right way ... In the contractor you should pass activity context...

Comment: I want to use AndroidViewModel which uses the application. To set the data in LiveModel, why will I need activity?

Comment: Even if I create viewModel = new MyViewModel(getApplication()); in MainActivity and MyTask, it won't work, because both use different instance of ViewModel?

Comment: From where are you starting the AsyncTask ?

Comment: The problem with creating new ViewModel instance using appContext is that ...your viewmodel won't be able to observe the lifecycle of the acitivty ...it would update the livedata even if the the activity is killed and there might be crashes @dcanh21

Comment: Yes, that is totally fine. I just want to update the LiveData even if there is no activity listening.

Comment: `I just want to update the liveData of **the** viewmodel ?` It's not the viewmodel... It becomes *another viewmodel* instead when you create new instance